# Python Jinja2 Render HTML template in certain style from strings

Tags: python, html, file, format, jinja2

I am new to using Jinja2 and am trying to render an html file from several strings and lists.

Lets say I have a File path, a term, and a sentence.

Using these I want to create an html file which has the file path as well as the two sentences where the the word is bolded if it matches the term.

I.e.

file_path is "/usr/bin/local/cheese.txt"

term is "cheese"

sentence is "i am cheese cheese i am"

I want to create and html file that looks like this

```
<html>
    <body>
    <h2>Search results for <b>cheese</b> in the file</h2>

        <p><a href="/usr/bin/local/cheese.txt">/usr/bin/local/cheese.txt</a><br>
         I am <b>cheese</b> <b>cheese</b> I am<br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

I have been trying to use Jinja2 but am having trouble creating an HTML file by specifying the formatting.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import jinja2
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

def render_template(template_filename, context):
    return TEMPLATE_ENVIRONMENT.get_template(template_filename).render(context)




file_path = "/usr/bin/local/cheese.txt"



term = "cheese"

sentence = "i am cheese cheese i am"

context = {
         'h2': "Search results for <b>" + terms + "</b>",
        'urls': file_path, # for making the file path tag - not sure if right
        'bold': term, # Do not think this is correct
        'paragraph': sentence ## Do not think this is correct at all.

    }

output = template.render_template("temp.html", context)
```

I do not think this is correct, but if someone who knows Jinja2 please tell me how to format this correctly I would be most grateful.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You want to learn how to render data from python objects in HTML file with Jinja2?

Comment: Yeah I have these three strings and I want to use Jinja2 to generate a HTML file in the format described above, but I have no idea how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an example of your code in jinja2:

Python:

```
from jinja2 import Template


def render_template(template_filename, context):
    with open(template_filename) as file_:
        template = Template(file_.read())
    return template.render(context)


file_path = "/usr/bin/local/cheese.txt"
term = "cheese"
sentence = "i am cheese cheese i am"
if term in sentence:
    sentence = sentence.replace(term, '<b>%s</b>' % term)
context = {
        'h2': "Search results for <b>" + term + "</b>",
        'urls': file_path,
        'bold': term,
        'paragraph': sentence

    }

output = render_template(your_template, context)
print(output)
```

Your template:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <h2>{{ h2|safe }}</h2>

        <p><a href="{{ urls }}}}">{{ urls }}}}</a><br>
         {{ paragraph|safe }}<br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would I use this with python. Would I do render_template(the above template as a string, values). Also how would I add the bold characters? Mainly though how do I use this with the above python functions?